# Why I am not able to get select2 dropdown previous value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I am not able to get select2 dropdown previous value

Below is the design part of dropdown

[image]

To resolve I have retry multiple code but none of them work for me.

Below are the code which I have tried

```
const $country = $content.find('.input.LOSS_STATS_COUNTRY');
```

Code : 1

```
$country.on('change', function () {
    debugger;
    var newStatus = $(this).val();
    var oldStatus = $(this).data('pre');
    console.log(newStatus+"-"+oldStatus);
}).data('pre', $country.val());
```

Code : 2

```
$country.on('focusin', function(){
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

$country.on('change', e => {
    debugger;
        let before_change = $country.data('val');
        console.log(before_change);
        const country = $country.val();           
    });
```

code : 3

```
$country.select2({}).focus(function () {
    debugger;
    console.log(v.target.value);

    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    $(this).data('pre', $(this).val());
}).on('change', e => {
    debugger;
        let before_change = $country.data('pre');
        console.log(before_change);
        const country = $country.val();            
    });
```

Code : 4

```
   $country.click(function(v){
    debugger;
    console.log(v.target.value);
   
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    $(this).data('pre', $(this).val());
}).on('change', e => {
    debugger;
        let before_change = $country.data('pre');
        console.log(before_change);
        const country = $country.val();
       
    });
```

code : 5

```
 $country.on('focusin', function () {
    debugger;
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    $(this).data('pre', $(this).val());
}).on('change', e => {
    debugger;
        var before_change = $(this).data('pre');
        const country = $country.val();
        
    });
```

code : 6

```
$country.on('focusin', function () {
    debugger;
    // Store the current value on focus and on change
    $(this).data('pre', $(this).val());
}).on('change', e => {
    debugger;
        var before_change = $(this).data('pre');
        const country = $country.val();
        
    });
```

On select2 of dropdown my focus/focusing/click event is not called and because of that I am not able to set the previous value.
I want my previous value before change event of dropdown is called manually

Note : On select2 dropdown change my change event is called but other events are not called

Comment: You're using a `select2` "overlay" - use the [tag:select2] API.   Try all your code with a basic `select` without the select2 plugin/replacement and see what you get.

Comment: @freedomn-m Can you please post your answer, I cannot change select2 to select

Comment: Cannot? or will not?    *try* it without select2 so that you can be happy the code you're working on would have worked - then start again using select2 api

Comment: eg, you can't "focus" or "click" the `select` as it's not visible

Comment: Your "code 1" should work (even with select2) if you move the `.data('pre', $country.val());` *inside* the `change` event, otherwise it never updates the previous value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `change` works with [select2](/questions/tagged/select2).

Focus/Click do not work as the underlying `select` has been hidden by the [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) wrapper.

It's unclear the requirement, if you want "initial value" vs "value before the current value", to get "previous value" you need to update with the "current" value when it changes.

```js
$('.select2').select2();

var $country = $(".select2");

$country.on('change', function () {
    var newStatus = $(this).val();
    var oldStatus = $(this).data('pre');

    // add this line
    $country.data('pre', newStatus);
    
    console.log(newStatus+"-"+oldStatus);
}).data('pre', $country.val());
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<!-- no indication what was in OPs select, so using starter entries -->
<select class="select2">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can we have some trick where we can check that the dropdown change event is changed manually and not by the code?